# Unable to import plotly express in my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

While importing plotly express in my jupyter notebook I am getting the below error:
 `AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'utils'`

I am using plotly version 5.17.0. I have made no changes to my environment and it used to work just fine before.

I tried running the below import command:
`import plotly.express as px`

And got the below error:
`AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'utils'`

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it? `python -m pip uninstall plotly -y; python -m pip install plotly --no-cache`

Comment: Hello @C.Nivs thank you for the response! I actually ran the `!pip install plotly --upgrade` command and it fixed the issue